# Problem while dual booting linux in acer laptop

Tags: dual-boot

I have I have bought an Acer nitro 5 laptop with 1TB hdd + 256gb ssd,, i installed linux on hdd but can't boot linux. It only boots up windows all the time. I tried to change the boot order in bios, but it only shows windows boot manager. I also tried F2 to select the 1TB hdd in which linux is installed but it only shows the ssd which has windows. I tried many linux distros..

Comment: No,,, there is no option for legacy mode tgere is only uefi mode in bios in my laptop

Answer (score 0):

try to install windows and linux in legacy mode. it works on acer laptops.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  To be useful, your answer should be more detailled, explaining how to do it, at least in a nutshell with possible links to more complete sources.